# Let $a$ be a complex zero of $x^2+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})=\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $a$ be a complex zero of $x^2+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})=\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

Let $f(x)=x^2+x+1$. Then $f(a)=a^2+a+1=0$.

To show equality of the two fields, we need to show containment of each one in the other.

For the forward containment, I guess I could use $\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}=a\implies \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})\subset\mathbb{Q}(a)$

For backward containment,  I'm not sure. I might be doing this the wrong way, since I don't understand where $a$ being a complex zero of $f$ affects anything.

Comment: Are you sure about  $\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}=a\implies \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})\subset\mathbb{Q}(a)$
Consider this one   $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}=2 \not \implies \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subset\mathbb{Q}(2)=\mathbb{Q} $. The opposite of inclusion is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first implication is not correct it should be:
$$a=\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}\implies a\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})\implies \mathbb{Q}(a)\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})\ $$

in the second inclusion:
$$\sqrt{a}=1+a\implies \sqrt a\in \mathbb{Q}(a)\implies \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt a)\subset \mathbb{Q}(a)\ $$

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt{a}=1+a$?

Comment: because $(a+1)^2=a^2+2a+1=(a^2+a+1)+a=0+a=a$ we used $f(a)=a^2+a+1=0$

Answer (score 2):

$(a+1)^2 = a^2+2a+1 = a \,\,\,$

Comment: Could you explain the last step? How do we know that it is equal to $a$?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I understand.